# Print list in Bash and then run a command against each line

Tags: macos, bash

So I run the below command in Mac Bash:

```bsh
Callums-MacBook-Pro-2:chart melman$ helm list
NAME                    REVISION        UPDATED                         STATUS          CHART                   APP VERSION     NAMESPACE
dozing-sasquatch        1               Fri Sep 13 11:31:40 2019        FAILED          pointsapp-0.1.0         1.0.0           default  
exasperated-boxer       1               Fri Sep 13 11:04:56 2019        FAILED          pointsapp-0.1.0         1.0.0           default  
foolhardy-arachnid      1               Fri Sep 13 10:47:45 2019        FAILED          pointsapp-0.1.0         1.0.0           default  
harping-ant             1               Fri Sep 13 09:44:07 2019        FAILED          pointsapp-1.0.0         1.0.0           default  
jazzed-gecko            1               Fri Sep 13 10:41:47 2019        FAILED          pointsapp-1.0.0         1.0.0           default  
luminous-rattlesnake    1               Fri Sep 13 10:51:44 2019        FAILED          pointsapp-0.1.0         1.0.0           default  
oily-deer               1               Fri Sep 13 10:58:17 2019        DEPLOYED        pointsappv2-0.1.0       1.0             default  
old-greyhound           1               Fri Sep 13 11:27:36 2019        FAILED          pointsapp-0.1.0         1.0.0           default  
plinking-llama          1               Fri Sep 13 11:19:23 2019        FAILED          pointsapp-0.1.0         1.0.0           default  
pugnacious-numbat       1               Fri Sep 13 10:07:04 2019        FAILED          pointsapp-1.0.0         1.0.0           default  
telling-skunk           1               Fri Sep 13 10:05:35 2019        FAILED          pointsapp-1.0.0         1.0.0           default  
torpid-gopher           1               Fri Sep 13 10:46:49 2019        FAILED          pointsapp-0.1.0         1.0.0           default
```

How do I select all the names and pass them to `helm delete [name]`, can this be done in a single command?

Comment: You'll need to loop through each of the lines and do the actions with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming none of the names contain white space, you can use a `for` loop to cycle through the list lines, piped into `tail` to skip the header line and then `awk` to print only the 1st column:

```
for name in $(helm list | tail -n+2 | awk '{print $1}'); do helm delete $name; done
```

Are you sure you want to wipe the entire list?

E:To delete only the failed ones, throw in a `grep`:

```
for name in $(helm list | tail -n+2 | grep "FAILED" | awk '{print $1}'); do helm delete $name; done
```